# Webmaster Showing Desktop Pages in Mobile Usability errors

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot-mobile

I have same URL for both desktop and mobile content, but changes their format according to User-agent.

Google search console is showing error as "Touch elements too close" for some pages which are of desktop version. I do not have these pages on mobile site.

How can I tell google to differentiate between mobile and desktop pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the "same URL for both desktop and mobile content, but changes their format according to User-agent" then all pages available to desktop users will also be available for the mobile users.

Google will crawl your desktop site and then determine what happens when viewing those pages from a mobile device. It's the ones which aren't optimised that flag as errors.

The better long-term solution is probably to copy the mobile-friendly styles from optimised pages across everything site-wide. This will give the greatest number of users the best experience on whatever device they use.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, 

This may help, but my concern is not about a single page. Desktop version of my site is having way more pages than the mobile version. These additional pages are appeared as error in webmaster. 
can you suggest what can I do to prevent crawler to crawl them as mobile version.  

I don't want them to appear as error and also not want to include these pages in mobile site.

Comment: I get that, but I think identifying why pages should *not* be available on tablets etc. is important to your overall user experience.

Comment: Ok, Got that, Thanks, one more query.. do you think "vary user agent" will work for this?